# Why i have to declare constant Pi value to use Cos Function in Math.h?

Tags: c, math, degrees, trigonometry, radians

```
x = 60.0;
val = PI / 180.0;
ret = cos( x*val );
printf("The cosine of %lf is %lf degrees\n", x, ret);
```

Hi, I was self-studying about function in math.h then i tried to use COS fuction to find the cos of radius in the program . I try to find the explantion of this function that Why COS function requires adding Pi/180.0 in Cos function to calculate cos of radius properly . Thank you so much

Comment: Adding? You are multiplying. And this looks like homework to me.

Comment: What platform are you on? M_PI should already be declared in `math.h`. If you are on Windows you might need to do `#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES` before `#include <math.h>`

Comment: @MFisherKDX: The macro `M_PI` is not defined by the C standard. A conforming C implementation *may not* define `M_PI` in `<math.h>`, because it's an ordinary identifier that a user program can use for its own purposes. Some implementations, with some settings, may provide it as an extension.

Comment: It is my homework

Comment: This seems like more of a math question than a programming question. You should probably study a bit of trigonometry first before trying to use C trig functions. Note that "calculate cos of radius properly" makes no sense: you calculate the cosine of an _angle_, which is commonly measured in degrees or radians.

Comment: Recall from your high school calculus that the most natural unit for angles is radians.  Degrees are arbitrary, but radians are universal.  With radians, the derivative of sine is cosine, with no multiplicative factor.  Most serious math libraries use radians as the default unit for angles for trig functions.

Comment: Why do you need π? Because the degrees notation owes nothing to mathematics, only to arithmetic, where 360 is a convenient number easily divided into many exact fractions which are understood by people. But the mathematical series (such as Taylor) which are used to compute cosine don't work with degrees, but with radians, where π radians is 180 degrees.

Answer (score 3):

If you check the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/cos/), you'll see that `cos()` accepts an angle in radians, not degrees. By multiplying your angle of 60 degrees by `PI / 180.0`, you're converting it to radians.

Comment: so what if i want to convert back to degrees ?

Comment: Just flip the conversion factor: `ret * 180.0 / PI` or `ret / val`

Comment: @ChangNoi997 360 degrees equals 2*pi radians, so 180 degrees equals pi radians.  That's all you need to know to convert back and forth.